# Target branch is empty when merging using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm getting a Target branch empty drop-down list, on TFS:

***Source branch:** 
$/ProjectName/TEST/ApplicationName*

***Target branch:**
empty drop-down list, should have a "$/ProjectName/PROD/ApplicationName" option*

No idea why... The branch I want to merge to, exists...

I appreciate any tips to ensure the branch shows up on the drop down list. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... I was doing a Merge, when i needed to Branch!

***Source branch:** $/ProjectName/TEST/ApplicationName*

***Target branch name:** textbox, typing value "$/ProjectName/PROD/ApplicationName"*

I was able to promote from the TEST to the PROD branch now.

For the first promotion from TEST to PROD, I'm using a Branch, for the next ones, I'll use a Merge. (I'll post screenshots as soon as possible to show the dialogs.)